# Linux: .c and Makefile "How to create the .s and .o file so that I can use "make" in terminal?"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

Ok, I going to assume this is an easy question. I have a .c file and a Makefile. I'm using Linux 12.10 ubuntu if that matters. I am trying to understand how I write in terminal to get these two files to create an executable, source, and object file in the directory to where these two files are utilizing make. I have nasm installed but not sure if there is something else I need installed. This is currently what I am doing but can't seem to understand the basics behind what I can do in windows but can't seem to get it to work in linux. I have changed the Makefile to except linux.

I know this is probably super easy but I'm pretty new to linux and don't really understand some of the things I think I should be able to figure out pretty easily so I do apologize if this seems to easy.

```
$ make firstlab.c firstlab
```

is what I am typing in terminal after I am in the right directory. My 
feedback is "

```
make: Nothing to be done for `homework1.c'.
gcc     homework1.c   -o homework1
homework1.c: In function ‘main’:
homework1.c:20:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
homework1.c:21:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’ [enabled by default]
```

"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

int firstNumber = 0;
int secondNumber = 0;
int result = 0;

printf("Enter first value: ");
scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
printf("Enter second value: ");
scanf("%d", &secondNumber);

if(firstNumber >= secondNumber)
    result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
else if(secondNumber > firstNumber)
     result = secondNumber + firstNumber;

printf("Result: %d\n", result);



system("pause");
return result;
}
```

Make File:

```
##########H
PROJECT = Homework1
##################

CC   = gcc

# win 32
#RM = del

#linux
RM = rm -f

BIN  = $(PROJECT).exe
OBJ  = $(PROJECT).o  


all:    $(BIN)

clean:
${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN) $(PROJECT).s

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(PROJECT).exe 

$(OBJ): $(PROJECT).s
$(CC) -c $(PROJECT).s -o $(PROJECT).o 

$(PROJECT).s: $(PROJECT).c
$(CC) -c $(PROJECT).c -S  -masm=intel
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the makefile?

Comment: What do you need the .s or .o for? Just type `make homework1`. For a single .c to produce an executable, a Makefile is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a makefile?  The output you show doesn't seem to line up with that assumption.

`make firstlab.c firstlab` is a bit weird.  You could just replace it with `make firstlab` and it would have the same results. If you want an object file type, `make firstlab.o`.

All of that behaviour depends on `make`'s implicit rules.  You probably should write a makefile for your project to control the behaviour better.  To support creating the assembly file (`firstlab.s`) you'll have to do that anyway.  A rule something like:

```
%.s : %.c
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<
```

Should do it.  You can make similar rules for the executable and the object files.  I strongly recommend a quick glance at the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to get started.

To fix the `printf` and `scanf` warnings, add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your program.

Comment: Why not just edit your question to include them?  I don't want to download that.

Comment: ok..let me try this again. I guess I can understand you not wanting to download that

Comment: Just edit your question, copy/paste it in and then select it and pick the `{}` icon to format it as code.  Adding it as a comment is not recommended.  Also that looks like your program, not like a makefile.

Comment: OK...I just edited my original post..hopefully that will help..first is the c file and then the make file...so once again..trying to take these two files and trying to create a source, object, and executable with these two files in linux, but then be able to just type "make" in linux like in windows to run it(or something very similar to it)

Comment: It looks close - just add the `-o` flag on the .c->.s rule and I think you're good.  Assuming you have tabs in there in the right places, that is.

Comment: Well, the Makefile is done. That was provided by the instructor and works right out of the box for windows. and as far as getting it to run in linux all I was having to do was take the "#" out of the linux line and add to the windows line and it would run on linux. I guess what I am asking is what do I need to type in the terminal to get this to work because it should work with what is there. The RM = rm -f that is

Comment: Oh.  You just need to change your sourcefile name to `Homework1.c`.  With a capital `H`.  It needs to be in the same folder as your makefile, which must be named `makefile` or `Makefile` or `GNUmakefile`.

Comment: so, I type **make Homework1.c** and I'm getting no rule to make target 'Homework1.c"

Comment: No.  Just type `make`.  That's it.  Make sure your source file has the right name.  Capital H.

Comment: **make: *** No rule to make target `Homework1.c', needed by `Homework1.s'.  Stop.**  Thats what I get when I type just make in the folder with my Makefile..this in terminal that I type this..to bad you don't have google+ or something..maybe you can help me via screen share or something. Gosh, I hate linux and like it all at the same time..lol

Comment: Your source file has the wrong name.  Your first example shows it with a lowercase `h`, and that error message could only happen if it either weren't there or had the wrong name.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out..the problem was that the file name of the homework1.c was lower cased instead of upper cased like it was in the Makefile..once I renamed the homework1.c to "Homework1.c" and did a **make Homework1.c Homework1** it created the source, object, and executable file...so all in allit looks like I had everything right but needed to rename the stinking file..so upset that this is all it was...I only noticed that because you typed **Homework1.c** capitalized that I noticed this..thanks so much @Carl Norum for spending the time you did.

Comment: What?  I said *three times* in comments above that you needed a capital `H`.

Comment: and by the way..YOU were **Right**..all i needed to do was type **make** freaking A!! REally, thanks...no I was typing **Homework1.c** in terminal but the file itself was lower cased and yes you are right you did and it just wasn't clicking that that is was I needed to do. Been looking at so much today it just didn't click..sorry